# Saving ID3 tags on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, id3

So I want to make my app edit and save ID3 tags. I found on some site a long time ago on how to read them, here is this code in my app:

```
-(NSDictionary*)MP3InfoDictionary {
    AudioFileID fileID = nil;
    OSStatus err = noErr;

    err = AudioFileOpenURL( (CFURLRef) self, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
    if (err != noErr) {
    //NSLog(@"AudioFileOpenURL failed");
    }
    UInt32 id3DataSize = 0;
    char * rawID3Tag = NULL;

    err = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag, &id3DataSize, NULL);
    if (err != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"AudioFileGetPropeetyInfo failed for ID3 tag");
    }
    //NSLog(@"id3 data size is %lu bytes",id3DataSize);

    rawID3Tag = (char *) malloc(id3DataSize);
    if (rawID3Tag == NULL) {
    //NSLog(@"could not allocated %lu bytes of memory for ID3 tag", id3DataSize);
    }

    err = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag, &id3DataSize, rawID3Tag);
    if (err != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"AudioFileGetProperty failed for ID3 tag");
    }
    //NSLog(@"read %lu bytes of ID3 info", id3DataSize);

    CFDictionaryRef piDict = nil;
    UInt32 piDataSize = sizeof(piDict);
    free(rawID3Tag);
    err = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &piDataSize, &piDict);
    if (err != noErr) {
    //NSLog(@"AudioFileGetProperty failed for property info dictionary");
    }

    //NSLog(@"Property info:%@", (NSDictionary*)piDict);
    //CFShow(piDict);

    NSDictionary *MP3InfoDictionary = (NSDictionary*)piDict;
    if (MP3InfoDictionary != NULL) {
    return MP3InfoDictionary;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This code is in a NSURL category, the url is a file url of a mp3 in the documents directory of the iOS. It works 100%, I get all the titles, artwork, lyrics, etc. But now I want to save and overwrite values of the mp3 like artist, title, etc. On another post on here a guy posted that you use AudioFileSetProperty(), how do I use it correctly?

Apparently it's because of the kAudioFileReadPermission but It tells me that the mp3 is only readable, but that can't be true because another app I have can change ID3 tags and can on the same mp3 I've tried to edit.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, with the warning.  Have you considered just using one of the ID3 libraries that have been around for years instead of writing this low-level stuff yourself?

Comment: consider this; you can't edit the media files on your device because there is sandboxing. So you copy this mp3 to your project and you still can't edit it there (bundle files are protected either). But you can copy it to the caches or document directory. Just want to make sure you have permission to the working dir

Comment: Yes, all the .mp3 files are in the documents folder of the app.

Comment: Did you get any further here?

Comment: I have not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
See my first comment below. It appears AudioFile does not allow modifying the four types of files listed in the link.

Comment: I just noticed on the Technical Q&A on Apple's site: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1676/_index.html

Comment: I have tried the open url, I can read the ID3s perfectly but having trouble saving. I may have used AudioFileSetProperty() wrong, i use the file id and kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag, I dont know what to put for inDataSize and inDataProperty

Comment: I get the error "The operation couldn’t be completed." when trying to open the file with write permission.                       `AudioFileID fileID = nil;
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    
    err = AudioFileOpenURL( (__bridge CFURLRef) self, kAudioFileWritePermission, 0, &fileID);
    if (err != noErr) {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:err userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        NSLog(@"AudioFileOpenURL failed");
    }`

Comment: Ya, Im trying to save a ID3 tag for .mp3.